# Adding own javascript function in ASP.NET AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

On the page I am building, I have four buttons which show/hide (visible="true" || visible="false") certain div's. What I want is before the AJAX function is called, my own custom function be called, which animates opacity of current visible div to zero, then displays a loading image and finally after the AJAX function completes another custom function is called which animates the "to be" shown div from zero opacity to 1 and from left to right. What I am trying to accomplish is windows phone 7 kind of effect in the webpage. So, any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using Asp.net ajax then yo can achieve this by following these steps

Register your javascript methods with these statement.

```
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
```

Definition of registered methods

```
    function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args)
    {
        alert("Begin Request Handle called.");
    }

    function endRequestHandle(sender, Args)
    {
      alert("End Request Handle called.");
    }
```

Comment: Where would be the best place to register the methods? Page_Load?

Comment: could be in head tag or just before where body tag closing. You just to put in a way that they are available before you make ajax request

Comment: Do you have asp.net ajax toolkit installed and integrated in your project?

Comment: Yeah! Got it working, http://encosia.com/updated-your-webconfig-but-sys-is-still-undefined/ , Thanks adil!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a custom ajax handler in your code. For example, in your cs file:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool CustomAjaxMethod(string arg)
{
  // do work
  return true;
}
```

Then, in your aspx file:

```
<input type="button" value="Do Ajax Call" onclick="doWork();" />
```

And in javascript:

```
function doWork() {
  // do your 1st animation here
  PageMethods.CustomAjaxMethod('foo', callback);
}

function callback(result, userContext, methodName) {
  if (methodName == 'CustomAjaxMethod') {
    // may want to check result here
    // do your 2nd animation here 
  }
}
```